# Update single model property from view by clicking a button to assign DateTime.Now value to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to do something simple but I am fairly new with ASP MVC and the answer eludes me... I 've tried following the logic behind the Edit method but I have made a mess

For a simple Model "Orders" with 4 properties OrderId, Reference, DateIn, DateOut

I need a button on Index view for each row (of Orders) that when clicked will post to controller and update the DateOut property with current DateTime and return to Index.

I am trying to avoid having to go into Edit View that lets me update the whole model.

The view is something like

```
@model WebApp.Models.Order
.
.
.
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reference)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateIn)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOut)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <form asp-action="Index">
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.OrderId" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary/>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
</tbody>
```

controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id, [Bind("DateOut")] Order order)
        {
            if (id != order.OrderId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    order.DateOut = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2);
                    _context.Update(order);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!OrderExists(order.OrderId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }


            return View(order);
        }
```

obviously there's something horribly wrong with the above code...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"obviously there's something horribly wrong with the above code..."_ - that's not obvious. Tell us your observations.

Comment: Clicking the button takes me back to Index but DateOut is not updated. I am not sure how to debug this... sorry

Comment: Debugging is one of the most basic skills that any developer **must** know. If you don't know how, learn it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out... still messy but works for me. In case someone is interested:

view button:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Update" formaction="/Orders/Index/@item.OrderId" class="btn btn-primary />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id)
    {

        var order = await _context.Orders.FindAsync(id);
        if (order != null)
        {

            order.DateOut = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2);
            _context.Update(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```